# Calculate pi of a radian that can be negative or positive?

Tags: c++, angle, radians

I have a variable A which is a radian angle value. I also have a variable B that should always be PI away from A. How can I verify that B is PI off of A with 0.01 accuracy in negative or positive direction (C++)? A's value can be negative.

Comment: Isn't `b` just `a + pi`?

Comment: Would it be so if A would be negative or positive?

Comment: @NathanOliver or `a - pi`

Comment: @hedeic IIRC, it shouldn't matter.  You just keep circling around the unit circle

Comment: Are you assuming that angle values are equal modulo 2π, that is `B=A+5π` would satisfy the condition as `A + 5π = A+π` modulo (2π)?

Comment: [fmod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/fmod)?

Comment: `std::abs(std::abs(a - b) - pi) <= 0.01` might be an option, depending on other requirements (which you haven't stated).    Bear in mind that trig functions have period `2*pi`

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I'll check if I they help!

Comment: I'd normalize the angles for example between [0÷2pi) before checking their difference with something like: `template<T> T mod_2pi(T rad) noexcept { constexpr T twopi = 2.0 * std::numbers::pi_v<T>; rad=std::fmod(rad,twopi); if(rad<0.0) rad+=twopi; return rad; }`

Answer (score 0):

[Peter's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4706785/peter) answer in the comments suited well to this problem: std::abs(std::abs(a - b) - pi) <= 0.01